# It's possible to run a VB.Net exe in a remote server and use it with a browser?

Tags: vb.net

First of all, thank you for your job, i solved a lot of problems with stack overflow. But i can't solve this, so now i'm writing. It's my first question, i hope i'm doing right.

The problem I would like to solve is this: I would like to put an exe generated in Visual Basic .Net (with framework 4) in a server, and execute it in a client computer, with a browser, through internet. 
It's possible to do that? Or maybe there is a way to make it work at least for Windows computers?

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you want to write code in .NET that would be executed by the client's browser, that would be [Blazor](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/client) which is not fully out yet and has [no immediate plans](https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/171) to directly support VB.NET. If you want to have random exes executing on peoples computers, that would be malware.

Comment: If the code is on the server then by definition it cannot execute on the client machine. You will have to persuade the user to download the application first

Comment: The only other way is, if the computers are on the same local network you could share the folder where the exe is located and client users could visit that share and execute the program without copying it locally. But that will not work across the public internet